# Calculus Textbook After Linear Algebra

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

Is there an introductory textbook which covers Calculus I with the assumption that the student has already taken linear algebra -- and thus is familiar with vectors?  That is, I'm looking for a Calc I textbook that covers things like derivatives of vectors right from the beginning of differentiation and path integrals right from the beginning (or middle) of integration.

Comment: There are some classics by Spivak and Apostol which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I recommend this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/CalcI.aspx then see books like Apostol, when you need more depth in proofs.

Comment: @[both of you guys above me]  Spivak's *Calculus*  does not assume knowledge of vectors from what I remember and his *Calculus on Manifolds* is **definitely not** a Calculus I book.  From the TOC of Apostol's *Calculus I & II*, it looks like he just goes over vectors himself right before he starts on multivariable calculus.  Paul's Outline also takes the standard approach rather than the early-vectorial approach I'm looking for.  So thanks anyway, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.  I'm not positive that a book like I'm wanting exists.  I may just have to write one myself.

Comment: Why do you *not* want to start from single variable calculus? The only books that come to mind (Duistermaat Multivariate Real Analysis, Loomis & Sternberg Advanced Calculus, Dieudonne Foundations of Modern Analysis) actually assume a deeper mathematical maturity than a simple linear algebra class. I believe that a very skilled/smart student could jump into them without single variable calculus, but it will be difficult. Single variable calculus is one of the most intuitive subjects, and I think there is nothing to be gained from "skipping" it.

Comment: I didn't say the book shouldn't start with single variable calculus, it should just also cover functions from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^3$ somewhat as well.  The reason being to prepare students for their first course in classical mechanics a little better.  I have found in tutoring physics students that many just can't get their heads around topics like mechanical work which I think might be alleviated a bit if they had some mathematical exposure to path integration before taking mechanics.